# How can I close my modal by clicking the close button in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

How can I close my modal by clicking the close button in reactjs ? My closeModal function is not working. Help me please !!! When I click the close button, the modal does not close.

When, I click on open the modal button then it is working, but when i click on close button then close button is not working. I am using the hooks in my project. Below, I have mentioned my code :

Gallery.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import "./gallery.css"
import { FaChevronLeft, FaChevronRight } from "react-icons/fa";



const Gallery = ({ pictures, source1, source2, source3, source4, source5, source6, title }) => {
  const [clickedImg, setClickedImg] = useState(null);
  const [currentPictureIndex, setCurrentPictureIndex] = useState(0);


  const handleClick = (e, pictures, title ) => {
    setClickedImg({e, pictures, title })
    console.log("showmodal state before any click")
  };
  
  const closeModal = (e) => {
    try {
      if (e.target.classList.contains("dismiss")) {
        setClickedImg(null);
        console.log(e.target.classList.contains("dismiss"))
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleNextClick = () => {
    const nextIndex = currentPictureIndex === pictures.length - 1 ? 0 : currentPictureIndex + 1;
    setCurrentPictureIndex(nextIndex);
  };

  const handlePrevClick = () => {
      const prevIndex = currentPictureIndex === 0 ? pictures.length - 1 : currentPictureIndex - 1;
      setCurrentPictureIndex(prevIndex);
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="gallery" onClick={handleClick}>
        <div className="galleryBox1">
          <img src={source1} alt={title} className="galleryCard"/>
        </div>
        <div className="galleryBox2">
          <div className="galleryBox3">
            <div className="galleryBoxa">
              <img src={source2} alt={title} className="galleryCardTwo"/>
            </div>
            <div className="galleryBoxb">
              <img src={source3} alt={title} className="galleryCardTwo"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="galleryBox5">
            <div className="galleryBoxc">
              <img src={source4} alt={title} className="galleryCardTwo"/>
            </div>
            <div className="galleryBoxd">
              <img src={source5} alt={title} className="galleryCardTwo"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {
          clickedImg && (
            <div className="galleryModal dismiss" onClick={closeModal}>
                <img
                    src={pictures[currentPictureIndex]}
                    alt={title}
                    className="galleryModalImg"
                />
                <button className="galleryModalButton dismiss" onClick={closeModal}>
                    Fermer
                </button>
                {pictures.length !== 1 && (
                    <div className="galleryModalArrows" onClick={handleNextClick}>
                        <FaChevronRight className="galleryModalNext" />
                    </div>
                )}
                {pictures.length !== 1 && (
                    <div className="galleryModalArrows" onClick={handlePrevClick}>
                        <FaChevronLeft className="galleryModalPrev" />
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Gallery
```

How can I close my modal by clicking the close button in reactjs ?

Comment: Are the validations in the closeModal function necessary? Since the function is being called only from the modal can't you set the null state directly. Or am I missing something. Ideally the close should be a button.

Comment: Try to simplify the `closeModal` function to `const closeModal = () => setClickedImg(null);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the reason. As you have added onClick in the parent div `(className="gallery")`, That's why, whenever you are clicking on any button in the div it is triggering a click on the main div's `handleClick` method.

If you console on the `handleClick` and `closeModal` function. You will see that if you click on the close button you will see the console that is written in the `handleClick()` function.

So I tried to move the `onClick={handleClick}` from that parent div. And put it in a children div. You can put it on `className="galleryBox1"` this div or any other div. Then it will work fine.

Comment: If it works. You can upvote my answer. That will help others.